# What is the difference between chemico-chemists and physico-chemists according to Van't Hoff?

Tags: physics, chemistry

> “Whereas the chemico-chemists always find in industry a beautiful field of gold-laden soil, the physico-chemists stand somewhat farther off, especially those who seek only the greatest dilution, for in general there is little to make with watery solutions.”
>   -Jacobius Henricus Van’t Hoff.

What is the difference between the two according to Van't Hoff?

Comment: can you please give an exact reference to this citation?